# How to get the size of available and allocated memory in a Flutter Android production app?

Tags: memory, flutter, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I'd like to get the following info in a (production, not debug or test) Flutter Android app:

- number of allocated memory objects
- allocated memory
- free memory

How do I do that?

Comment: All I've seen that helps is the system_info plugin, but it's been discontinued.